# jq parse json log file

Tags: json

I have json log file like

```
{"type":"1","fname":"AAA","lname":"bbb" }
{"type":"2","state":"gujarat" }
{"type":"3","city":"ahmedabad" }
{"type":"3","city":"rajkot" }
{"type":"1","fname":"ccc","lname":"ddd" }
```

I run following command

```
jq -c "select(.type==\"1\")|{fname:.fname}" > type_1.txt
jq -c "select(.type==\"2\")|{city:.city}" > type_3.txt
```

Is anyway to run jq  command only one time and generate 2 output files?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to avoid second invocation of `jq`, sorry.